# Subtract each vector in a list from vectors in another list via numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm sure this one is easy in `numpy`, however I did not find the appropriate method. Basically I need something like `outer()` but for subtraction. Here is my working code via LC:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)))
b = np.array(((6,7,8), (6,3,1)))

print np.array([i-j for i in a for j in b])
```

Output:

```
[[-5 -5 -5]
 [-5 -1  2]
 [-4 -4 -4]
 [-4  0  3]
 [-3 -3 -3]
 [-3  1  4]]
```

Here is the speed comparison of the posted answers. `a` has 1000000 entries and `b` has 100:

```
In [22]: %timeit np.array([i-j for i in a for j in b])
1 loops, best of 3: 12.3 s per loop

In [23]: %timeit np.repeat(a,b.shape[0],0)-np.tile(b,(a.shape[0],1))
10 loops, best of 3: 50.1 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit (a[:,np.newaxis,:]-b).reshape(-1, 3)
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop
```

Comment: i guess with numpy.einsum (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), but you go from shapes (3,3), (2,3) to (6,3) so this is confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **np.repeat()** and **np.tile()** to repeat/tile the array

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(((1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,4,5)))
b = np.array(((6,7,8), (6,3,1)))
c = np.repeat(a,b.shape[0],0)-np.tile(b,(a.shape[0],1))

print c

array([[-5, -5, -5],
       [-5, -1,  2],
       [-4, -4, -4],
       [-4,  0,  3],
       [-3, -3, -3],
       [-3,  1,  4]])
```

Answer (score 7):

You could take advantage of broadcasting by reshaping `a` before subtraction, then reshaping again to get the desired result:

```
In [97]: (a[:,np.newaxis,:]-b).reshape(-1, 3)
Out[97]: 
array([[-5, -5, -5],
       [-5, -1,  2],
       [-4, -4, -4],
       [-4,  0,  3],
       [-3, -3, -3],
       [-3,  1,  4]])
```

---

Explanation:

```
In [101]: a.shape
Out[101]: (3, 3)

In [99]: a[:,np.newaxis,:].shape
Out[99]: (3, 1, 3)

In [100]: b.shape
Out[100]: (2, 3)
```

When NumPy evaluates `a[:,np.newaxis,:]-b` it broadcasts the shapes of `a[:,np.newaxis,:]` and `b` both to `(3, 2, 3)` before subtraction. Roughly speaking, the first and second axes do not interact. The subtraction occurs only in the 3rd axis. The subtraction is performed for each location with respect to the first and second axes. That's sort of the NumPy equivalent of

```
for i in a for j in b
```

The result is

```
In [102]: a[:,np.newaxis,:]-b
Out[102]: 
array([[[-5, -5, -5],
        [-5, -1,  2]],

       [[-4, -4, -4],
        [-4,  0,  3]],

       [[-3, -3, -3],
        [-3,  1,  4]]])

In [103]: (a[:,np.newaxis,:]-b).shape
Out[103]: (3, 2, 3)
```

The only thing left to be done is to reshape the result to get it in the desired form.

Comment: Great solution too, however I'm seeking for performance and Abid provided a faster one. +1 though! Thanks

Comment: Oops... I thought this one would be more faster. Did you check it?

Comment: Yea I posted the timeit-results, see above. Nice one however : )

Comment: @septi: how does that happen. In my machine, this is 2x faster than mine.

Comment: @unutbu : Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Did you try it with bigger arrays?

Comment: I forgot to add the dimensions of `a` and `b`. `a` has in my case about 1000000 entries and `b` about 100. You probably tried with smaller arrays I guess?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: I'm surprised by the difference, but indeed your method is much faster for large arrays. (As long as the intermediate arrays fit in memory). Kudos to you!

Comment: Thank you, Actually, I expected mine to be slower since I am creating intermediate arrays.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: Maybe there is some super speed-up for subtraction of arrays in contiguous chunks of memory, which makes it faster than looping over indices which is (I guess) what broadcasting requires.

Comment: OK, that might be a good reason. So, regarding memory-utilization, your method will be better, I think, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe septi used some old numpy version?

Comment: @seberg: It appears septi, AbidRahmanK, and I all agree AbidRahmanK's method is faster for large arrays. Do you see a different result?

Comment: @unutbu, yeah, I had this as being faster, maybe I timed something differently, but sounds odd that it would be slower, unless the reshape is not possible in place.